# How to add label AFTER drawing a path

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am drawing a tree in tikz (similar to binary search tree). I use for loops to create the nodes and edges. After I create them, I would like to add description to some nodes and edges. With nodes, I don't have an issue as I can reference them. For edges, how would I reference a specific edge so I can put a label next to it without having to redraw that edge.

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{>=stealth}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[darkstyle/.style={circle,fill=black,minimum size=15}]
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\scale}{1.5} % Scale of distance between nodes
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\maxDepth}{4} % max depth

  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\maxDepthLessOne}{\maxDepth-1} % max depth - 1
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\maxDepthLessTwo}{\maxDepth-2} % max depth - 2
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\halfway}{\maxDepthLessOne/2} % floor((max depth - 1)/2)
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\otherhalfway}{\maxDepthLessOne-\halfway} % ceil((max depth - 1)/2)

  % create nodes
  \foreach \curDepth in {0,...,\maxDepthLessOne} % current depth
    \foreach \pos in {0,...,\curDepth} % horizontal
    {
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\verPos}{1-\curDepth}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\horPos}{\pos-\curDepth/2}
      \node [darkstyle] (node\curDepth\pos) at (\scale*\horPos,\scale*\verPos) {};
    }

  % create edges
  \foreach \curDepth in {0,...,\maxDepthLessTwo} % current depth
    \foreach \pos in {0,...,\curDepth} % horizontal
    {
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nextDepth}{\curDepth+1}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nextPos}{\pos+1}
      \draw [->,blue,ultra thick] (node\curDepth\pos)--(node\nextDepth\pos);
      \draw [->,red,ultra thick] (node\curDepth\pos)--(node\nextDepth\nextPos);
    }

  \node [left=8] at (node20) {testt}; %testt

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is to use coordinate during creation:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{>=stealth}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[darkstyle/.style={circle,fill=black,minimum size=15}]
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\scale}{1.5} % Scale of distance between nodes
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\maxDepth}{4} % max depth

  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\maxDepthLessOne}{\maxDepth-1} % max depth - 1
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\maxDepthLessTwo}{\maxDepth-2} % max depth - 2
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\halfway}{\maxDepthLessOne/2} % floor((max depth - 1)/2)
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\otherhalfway}{\maxDepthLessOne-\halfway} % ceil((max depth - 1)/2)

  % create nodes
  \foreach \curDepth in {0,...,\maxDepthLessOne} % current depth
    \foreach \pos in {0,...,\curDepth} % horizontal
    {
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\verPos}{1-\curDepth}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\horPos}{\pos-\curDepth/2}
      \node [darkstyle] (node\curDepth\pos) at (\scale*\horPos,\scale*\verPos) {};
    }

  % create edges
  \foreach \curDepth in {0,...,\maxDepthLessTwo} % current depth
    \foreach \pos in {0,...,\curDepth} % horizontal
    {
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nextDepth}{\curDepth+1}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nextPos}{\pos+1}
      \draw [->,blue,ultra thick] (node\curDepth\pos)--(node\nextDepth\pos)coordinate[midway] (ArrowA\curDepth_\pos);
      \draw [->,red,ultra thick] (node\curDepth\pos)--(node\nextDepth\nextPos) coordinate[midway] (ArrowB\curDepth_\pos);
    }

  \node[left] at (node20) {testt}; %testt
  \node [left={of ArrowB1_0}] {\begin{minipage}{1.2cm}Text Added!\end{minipage}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am guessing I can't do it without a shift because of how I drew the edges.

Comment: @Topa ... You can, the problem was with my `text width` ... But using a minipage will work (see edit). Then just a really small shift could help... But `anchor=east`  or `left` could work as expected

Answer (score 6):

One possibility is to use `calc` to determine the middle between nodes. You could also use `\path` together with, say, `midway`.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{>=stealth}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[darkstyle/.style={circle,fill=black,minimum size=15}]
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\scale}{1.5} % Scale of distance between nodes
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\maxDepth}{4} % max depth

  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\maxDepthLessOne}{\maxDepth-1} % max depth - 1
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\maxDepthLessTwo}{\maxDepth-2} % max depth - 2
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\halfway}{\maxDepthLessOne/2} % floor((max depth - 1)/2)
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\otherhalfway}{\maxDepthLessOne-\halfway} % ceil((max depth - 1)/2)

  % create nodes
  \foreach \curDepth in {0,...,\maxDepthLessOne} % current depth
    \foreach \pos in {0,...,\curDepth} % horizontal
    {
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\verPos}{1-\curDepth}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\horPos}{\pos-\curDepth/2}
      \node [darkstyle] (node\curDepth\pos) at (\scale*\horPos,\scale*\verPos) {};
    }

  % create edges
  \foreach \curDepth in {0,...,\maxDepthLessTwo} % current depth
    \foreach \pos in {0,...,\curDepth} % horizontal
    {
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nextDepth}{\curDepth+1}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nextPos}{\pos+1}
      \draw [->,blue,ultra thick] (node\curDepth\pos)--(node\nextDepth\pos);
      \draw [->,red,ultra thick] (node\curDepth\pos)--(node\nextDepth\nextPos);
    }

  \node [left=8] at (node20) {testt}; %testt
  \node [left=5] at ($(node20)!0.5!(node10)$) {text}; %testt
  \path (node11) -- (node22) node[midway,right=5] {text}; %testt
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great Suggestion. However, the position is not that accurate and would be difficult for non-trivial paths. There was another answer by @koleygr which is exactly what I needed (even better). Hopefully, he can resubmit his answer or I'll post it later.

Comment: @Topa try `\path (node10) -- (node20) node[midway,anchor=east] {text}; %test` it is the same... Undeleting my answer for 5 minutes too...

Comment: @koleygr Yeah that would be a solution for my trivial example but your other solution gives me a reference to the paths for more complex cases.

Comment: Ok @Topa ... I improve that for your case ... But sure someone else could make it without shifts too.

Answer (score 0):

I see that we can do it naturally with some usual TikZ's commands. Using `xscale=.75` to make figure narrower. There is no `edge` in the below code. We can use `foreach` to shorten the code a bit.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%xscale=.75,
n/.style={circle,fill,minimum size=5mm},
ar/.style={line width=2pt,-stealth}]
\def\a{2}
\path
(0,0)       node[n] (1)  {}
++(-120:\a) node[n] (2a) {}
+(0:\a)     node[n] (2b) {}
++(-120:\a) node[n] (3a) {}
+(0:\a)     node[n] (3b) {}
+(0:2*\a)   node[n] (3c) {}
++(-120:\a) node[n] (4a) {}
+(0:\a)     node[n] (4b) {}
+(0:2*\a)   node[n] (4c) {}
+(0:3*\a)   node[n] (4d) {};

\draw[ar,blue] (1)--(2a); 
\draw[ar,blue] (2a)--(3a); 
\draw[ar,blue] (2b)--(3b); 
\draw[ar,blue] (3a)--(4a);
\draw[ar,blue] (3b)--(4b);
\draw[ar,blue] (3c)--(4c);

\draw[ar,red] (1)--(2b);
\draw[ar,red] (2a)--(3b);
\draw[ar,red] (2b)--(3c);
\draw[ar,red] (3a)--(4b);
\draw[ar,red] (3b)--(4c);
\draw[ar,red] (3c)--(4d);

\draw[ar,blue] (2a)--(3a) 
node[left=2mm,black]{The left of 3rd row!} 
node[pos=.3,align=right,red,left=2mm]{YOU WANT\\TEXT HERE};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```